# Lookup user information in Microsoft Graph from a console app

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to lookup people Name and email address using their ADID/SAMAccountName/UPN from a console app running with its own credentials and not under my account.

How would I do this with Microsoft Graph?

I was following up on https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2 but that seem to require admin access. (BTW is there an easy way to figure out the admin  on my company's graph?)

I did lookup LDAP querying but domain limitations limit the search scope ,and would rather do this via Microsoft Graph.

Comment: The application permissions need admin consent , you may ask IT support for that .

Comment: To answer you "BTW" question, yes. Easiest is with the [AzureAD PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0): `Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Company Administrator" } | Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember`

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret Thanks this helped !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing Microsoft Graph [without user credentials](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) (i.e. using the OAUTH client credentials flow) requires [Admin Consent](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service#3-get-administrator-consent) for your application. Typically this consent would be handled by your IT department.